# seq_along giving the column number not row number

Tags: r, seq

I'm trying to write a for loop that creates a new variable from an existing variable in a dataframe, and does so by iterating over each row in turn. I've tried using `for (i in seq_along(data))`, but this only created the new variable correctly for the first 19 rows, and I realised that `seq_along` wasn't working as I had expected: instead of creating the sequence based on the number of rows, it had done so based on the number of columns:

`seq_along(data)` returns

`[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19`

while `nrow(data)` returns

`[1] 82`

and `ncol(data)` returns

`[1] 19`

Additionally, the output for `seq(data)` is the same as that for `seq_along`, and `length(data)` returns `[1] 19`.

While I've got a workaround that resolves the issue for the for loop (`for (i in 1:nrow(data))`), I'm curious to know what the reason is for `seq_along` (and `seq` and `length`) not behaving the way I'd expected.

Comment: We need `seq_len(nrow(data))`  By default, `seq_along` is looking at the column sequence.  `len` of python and `length` of `R` is different.

Comment: The reason is that a data frame is essentially a list of vectors that are all equally long. Try `is.list(data)` or check out the respective book section in [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#data-frames). So `length()` or `seq_along()` take the length of the list, that is, the number of columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Formalizing the comments into a community answer, `seq_along(aDataFrame)` sequences along columns in a data frame because a data frame is also a `list()`. We can demonstrate this with the `typeof()` function as follows with the Motor Trend Cars data frame.

```
> typeof(mtcars)
[1] "list"
```

Each element in the list contains one column from a data frame. We can use the `names()` function to extract the element names from the list.

```
> names(mtcars)
[1] "mpg"  "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
```

Therefore, `seq_along(mtcars)` will produce a vector of 1:11, corresponding to the number of elements in the `list()`.

```
> seq_along(mtcars)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, you can use:

`mtcars %>% mutate(ID = row_number())`

The result will look like this:

[image]